# update database when click on submit button

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm new to php and I have searched through in stackoverflow for answers but non prevail.
My question is how to update database using the submit button. below is my code for submit button.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$sql="UPDATE leaveapp SET status = Approve WHERE leaveappid = '13'";
        }               
?>
<form action="approve.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" id='approve' value="Yes" name="action" class="approve" />
</form>
```

the submit button was suppose to update table leaveapp and set status to approve where the leaveappid is = 13 but whenever I click on the submit button, It did not update the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <?php
     $link = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME", "USERNAME", "PASS", "DBNAME");
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $sql="UPDATE leaveapp SET status = 'Approve' WHERE leaveappid = 13";
    mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!this code help me big time!

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql to this

```
$sql="UPDATE leaveapp SET status = 'Approve' WHERE leaveappid = '13'";
```

You need to put single qoutes around Approve. and then execute it using

```
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Comment: `mysql_query`? why not `mysqli`?

Comment: this code also work. thx!

Comment: Sir I have one more question. If I put another button for example 'NO' button where it updates the database and changed the status to Reject. How would I put the if statement as the both yes and no button is a input type =submit

Comment: You don't need to worry with submit type, instead give your submit button a name let say "No", then on php page check for if(isset($_POST['No'])) {} inside this put your Reject code

Comment: That's fine you are ready to go